# When should I use CYCLE in a sequence?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-sequence

I'm using sequences in a PostgreSQL database to insert rows into tables.

When creating the sequences I have never used the `CYCLE` option on them. I mean they can generate pretty big numbers (in the order of 2^63 as far as I remeber) and I don't really see why I would like a sequence to go back to zero. So my question is:

When should I use `CYCLE` while creating a sequence?

Do you have an example where it makes sense?

Comment: For example when you want values 1 to 100, and then start over.

Comment: Ah... not as a primary key, but for other uses, such as a "bingo" game or "ticket" printing, etc. that use small numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a sequence can use `CYCLE` for other purposes rather than for primary key generation.

This is, in scenarios where the uniqueness of its value is not required; actually is quite the opposite, when the values are expected to cycle back and repeat themselves after some time.

For example:

- When generating numbers that must return to the initial value and repeat themselves at some point, for any reason (e.g. implementing a "Bingo" game).
- When the sequence is a temporary identifier that will last for a short period of time and will be unique during its life.
- When the field is small -- or can accept a limited number of values -- and it doesn't matter if they repeat themselves.
- When there is another field in the entity that will identify it, and the sequence value is used for something else.
- When an entity has a composite unique key and the sequence value is only a part of it.
- When using the sequence value to generate uniform distribution of values on a big set, though this is hardly a random assignation of values.
- Any other cyclic number generation.